# All Checkbox Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to see if all checkboxes are selected using jQuery.

Basically when all three options are selected I want to display only the mobile number.

If only the last option is selected show the home number.

If all three are selected show mobile and keep home hidden.

I've managed to get the case where if the user clicks on the last option show the home number but not if all three are selected.

See my jQuery below...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn2fJ/77/)

```
    var form = {

    init: function() {
        form.selection();
        form.showHomeNumber();
    },

    selection: function() {
        var option = $('.checkbox');

        option.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).children().prop( 'checked', !$(this).children().prop('checked') );

        });
    },

    //If I select only the last option show home number
    showHomeNumber: function() {
        var homeNumber = $('.home-number'),
            lastOption = $('.last-option'),
            mobileNumber = $('.mobile-number');

        lastOption.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //If all three are selected show mobile, hide home
            if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length === 3) {
               mobileNumber.css('display', 'block'); 
               homeNumber.hide();
            }
            //If select last option only show home
            homeNumber.toggleClass('home-active');
            //If select last option only hide mobile
            mobileNumber.toggleClass('mobile-inactive');


        });
    }
}
$(function(){
    form.init();
});
```

Comment: A little confusing since you aren't actually letting the checkboxes stay checked...

Comment: approach is very strange, why are you trying to bypass events on checkboxes themselves? Making it more difficult for yourself. `<label>` will pass events though even if you hide the actual checkbox

Comment: also there's a conflict in statement about what should show , 2 variations based on all selected

Comment: 2 mistakes,the input element is not the children of li,li's children is label,and the label's children is the input:checkbox,so he shoud use jquery find method,not the children method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do this way:

```
 $("li.checkbox").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //If all three are selected show mobile, hide home
            if ($("ul li.checkbox.active").length > 1) {
                mobileNumber.css('display', 'block');
                homeNumber.hide();
            } else if ($("li.last-option").hasClass("active")) {
                //If select last option only show home
                homeNumber.toggleClass('home-active');
                homeNumber.show();
                mobileNumber.hide();
                //If select last option only hide mobile
                mobileNumber.toggleClass('mobile-inactive');
            }

        });
```

### DEMO:

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn2fJ/86/)

[**UPDATED WITH CHECKBOX WORKING**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/Qn2fJ/91/)

Comment: This works well however, when you select the last option to active and then deselect it. The mobile number should appear rather than the home. Can you help?

Comment: That's fantastic! Update your code and your fiddle in your answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks again!

Comment: its because of `preventDefault()` let me correct that as well

Comment: @Filth When options 1 and 3 are selected (but not 2), it still says "Mobile number." Is that the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Guessing your html try something like this:

```
$('form input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
  if ($('form input:checkbox').length == $('form input:checkbox:checked').length) {
    console.log('All checkboxes are checked');
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

Oh I see, the issue is your selector `form input:checkbox:checked` since your checkboxes are not inside your form tag, you have two possible solutions: change `<form>` to be the first line in your html or remove the word "form" from your selector

Also you have to do a handle for any checkbox not only the last one so you can verify the condition when any of them is clicked.

Comment: There is a jsfiddle in my question containing the HTML etc...I will try what you've posted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if($( "input:checked" ).length === 3) {
            //show mobile number hide home
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 mistakes :

1. $(this).children().prop( 'checked', !$(this).children().prop('checked') );

'this' is li,li's children is label ,not the input .so you need modify it to this:

```
$(this).find('input').prop( 'checked', !$(this).find('input').prop('checked') );
```

1. if ($("form input:checkbox:checked").length === 3) {

the input:checkbox element is not inside the form ,so you need to remove the form,like this:

```
if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length === 3)
```

good luck!